# Changing Actionbar Tab Text Size in AppCompact Theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I've search around and tried several ways to change the Actionbar Tab text style.

[image]

I would like the bigger text size for that "NOW SHOWING" text.

Here's my Theme.

```
  <style name="Theme.Tabtheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_tabtheme</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Tabtheme</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Tabtheme</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Tabtheme</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTabTextStyle.Tabtheme</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTabTextStyle.Tabtheme</item>

    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Tabtheme</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Tabtheme</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_tabtheme</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_tabtheme</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Tabtheme</item>

    <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Tabtheme.Widget</item>

  </style>

  <style name="ActionBarTabTextStyle.Tabtheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Base.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
  </style>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me . I am able to change the text size and color.  Try removing the `actionBarWidgetTheme`

```
<style name="Theme.Tabtheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTabTextStyle.Tabtheme</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTabTextStyle.Tabtheme</item>

</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabTextStyle.Tabtheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Base.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/Red</item>
</style>
```