# Xamarin Forms MasterDetail Center Title

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms-styles

I'm starting my first Xamarin Forms application - little more than Hello World at the moment - however I need to be able to Center the text in the title bar.  I'm using a MasterDetailPage which has a ContentPage as Master and a NavigationPage as Detail.  From the screen shot below I'd like to be able to center 'Home'.

I've tried markup like the answer from [Changing Actionbar Tab Text Size in AppCompact Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23379122/changing-actionbar-tab-text-size-in-appcompact-theme) however nothing seems to affect the position of the text.  I also tried a custom renderer, however that didn't work.

Has anyone been able to do this?

Updating my question with some code.  My MasterDeatil.cs:

```
public class MasterDetail : MasterDetailPage
    {
        Master master;

        public MasterDetail()
        {
            master = new Master();

            Master = master;
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new Home());

            master.ListView.ItemSelected += ListView_ItemSelected;

            ToolbarItem cart = new ToolbarItem()
            {
                Text = "Test",
                Icon = "shoppingcart.png"
            };

            cart.Clicked += async (object sender, System.EventArgs e) =>
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Done", "Msg", "Ok", "Can");
            };

            ToolbarItems.Add(cart);
        }

        private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MasterItem item = e.SelectedItem as MasterItem;

            if (item != null)
            {
                Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
                master.ListView.SelectedItem = null;
                IsPresented = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Code for Master.cs:

```
public class MasterDetail : MasterDetailPage
    {
        Master master;

        public MasterDetail()
        {
            master = new Master();

            Master = master;
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new Home());

            master.ListView.ItemSelected += ListView_ItemSelected;

            ToolbarItem cart = new ToolbarItem()
            {
                Text = "Test",
                Icon = "shoppingcart.png"
            };

            cart.Clicked += async (object sender, System.EventArgs e) =>
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Done", "Msg", "Ok", "Can");
            };

            ToolbarItems.Add(cart);
        }

        private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MasterItem item = e.SelectedItem as MasterItem;

            if (item != null)
            {
                Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
                master.ListView.SelectedItem = null;
                IsPresented = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Code for Detail.cs:

```
public class Detail : ContentPage
    {
        public Detail()
        {
            Title = "Shaves2U";
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = {
                    new Label {
                        Text = "Detail data goes here",
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

I have tried the following style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/CustomTab</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>
  <style name="CustomTab" parent="@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I'm hoping I've just got the XML wrong

[image]

Comment: Could you include some code of how you have constructed your `MasterDetailPage`? With just a screenshot attached to your question, it is difficult to know how we are to assist you. Also, please do note that `Xamarin.Forms` uses the default behaviour of the respective platforms. When it comes to the title of a master-detail page for Android, the title is normally always left aligned.

Comment: @Demitrian, I've updated the question with some source code

Comment: Take a look on this:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59722/toolbar-title-set-center-align

Comment: @YuraBabiy, thanks for the reply - however I have read that post and it didn't help

Comment: Have you solved this case? I've investigated this issue for some days, only I can have a workaround, and this method is not quite elegant to me...The biggest problem I'm facing now is that I can't get the rendered `ToolBar`'s context, I used MainActivity as its context, but seems to be a wrong one.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT, unfortunately I haven't solved this yet - I'll post any updates I have. Do you have any information on your work around?

Comment: @markpirvine, I wrote an answer to explain what I've done, please have a check.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I think we can solve it now. Somehow I now can change the title, not sure what happened with my old project.

Comment: No, I still haven't solved it - how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here I will post my research on this question, so can we keep on digging this issue and avoid making my mistakes again.

Please remember the two important conditions for this case: 1. `MasterDetailPage` control for mater/detail layout; 2. `ContentPage` control for detail pages' layout.

1. The `Title` is not the title of the `Toolbar` in android project, it's the title of `ContentPage`. You can check this by commenting out the code `ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;` in the `MainActivity`'s `OnCreate` method, or by removing the value of `Title` for each `ContentPage`. So modifying the style of `Toolbar` will never work here.
2. Based on the first result, the idea comes nature that we can remove the the value of `Title` for each `ContentPage`, and together modifying the layout of `Toolbar` like this.

Toolbar.axml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="11111"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

It looks well, the title is in the center, but now it comes the second question: how to change the title text when the detail page is selected.

3. To solve the second problem, I create a customer render for both 3 detail `ContentPage` and add assemblies for this render.

For the part of custom `ContentPage` render, you can refer to [Customizing a ContentPage](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/contentpage/), I added assemblies like this:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContactsPage), typeof(MyPageRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ReminderPage), typeof(MyPageRenderer))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TodoListPage), typeof(MyPageRenderer))]
```

It solve the problem, we can get the `ContentPage`'s name in the `OnElementChanged` method like this:

```cs
var pageName = e.NewElement.GetType().FullName;
```

Seems OK and now comes to our last question: How to set the page name to the title of `Toolbar`, and this is the exact key problem I'm stick now.

In the `MainActivity` I coded like this:

```cs
var factory = LayoutInflater.From(this);
var bar = factory.Inflate(ToolbarResource, null);
var tv = (TextView)bar.FindViewById(Resource.Id.mytitle);
tv.SetText("sdff", TextView.BufferType.Normal);
```

It can find the `TextView`, and the text of `TextView` is "11111" which is set in xml for test, but the new `Text` can never be set successfully.

Firstly I thought the UI operation should be done in the UIThread, so I put the code in `RunOnUiThread` or in `new Handler(Looper.MainLooper)`, but still does it not work. Then I think maybe I get the wrong `Toolbar` due to the wrong `Context`: `var factory = LayoutInflater.From(this);`, but I could never find the right context here. I also tried to find the fragments since the source code of `MasterDetailPage` used `Fragment`, all failed.

Then I begin to think, why not we create our toolbar, not use `ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;` to create the toolbar. But by check the source code of `FormsAppCompatActivity`, I found this code:

```cs
if (ToolbarResource != 0)
{
    bar = LayoutInflater.Inflate(ToolbarResource, null).JavaCast<AToolbar>();
    if (bar == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("ToolbarResource must be set to a Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar");
}
else
    bar = new AToolbar(this);

SetSupportActionBar(bar);
```

I will never success to set toolbar by our self when our `MainActivity` is inherited from `FormsAppCompatActivity`.

Finally I think maybe I can change the `MainActivity` inherit from `global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity` instead from `global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity`, so can we set the `Toolbar` by our self, still failed, it will throw a `NullReferenceException` at the line `LoadApplication(new App());` and I'm in a dead end again.

So comes to my workaround, create a custom render for `MasterDetailPage`, and in the `OnElementChanged`, create a `TextView` or something and lay this control in the top center, change the text also from the custom render of `ContentPage`.

But I would call this a stupid, stubborn idea rather then a workaround, cause by doing all these lot of work, why not build our own view using the native android control instead of using xamarin's `MasterDetailPage`? Unless we can find a way to set the `Text` of original `Toolbar`, creating our own master detail view for android app should also be a workaround, a better one I think.

Comment: Hi Grace, great finding, you've saved hours of research work there, did you find any other solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a pretty old question, I found it when looking for other stuff. The solution is pretty simple in Xamarin Forms. Just add a ***NavigationPage.TitleView*** tag to your ***ContentPage***. This way you can add whatever you want with any style to the navigation bar:

ContentPage

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <Label Text="Centered Title" Style="{StaticResource TitleStyle}" />
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

Styles can be global (ie: in App.xaml):

```
<Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="TitleStyle">
  <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Medium" />
  <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```